# How do I make Pip respect requirements?

Tags: python, dependencies, pip

If I create a setup.py using `requires`, Pip doesn't install my dependencies.

Here's my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='my_project',
      description="Just a test project",
      version="1.0",
      py_modules=['sample'],
      requires=['requests'])
```

I wrote a simple sample.py:

```
import requests

def get_example():
    return requests.get("http://www.example.com")
```

I then try to install it:

```
$ pip install -e .                                                                                    [15:39:10]
Obtaining file:///tmp/example_pip
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///tmp/example_pip

Installing collected packages: my-project
  Running setup.py develop for my-project

    Creating /tmp/example_pip/my_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my-project.egg-link (link to .)
    Adding my-project 1.0 to easy-install.pth file

    Installed /tmp/example_pip
```

Note that `requests`, my dependency isn't installed. If I now try to use my test project:

```
$ python                                                                                              [15:35:40]
>>> import sample
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/example_pip/sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm surprised to see this closed as too localized -- it's a Pip problem I've seen a number of Python developers encounter. Would the closers please say why?

Comment: Indeed, the question comes up from time to time; I just marked [How do I make Pip respect requirements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12372336) as a dupe of this one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct spelling is `install_requires`, not `requires`; this does require that you use [`setuptools`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html), not `distutils`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_project',
      description="Just a test project",
      version="1.0",
      py_modules=['sample'],
      install_requires=['requests'])
```

I can recommend the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) for the nitty gritty details.

Comment: Thanks, seems that [the Python docs here](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages) led me astray. What purpose does `requires` fulfil?

Comment: @WilfredHughes: `distutils` actually predates automated tools such as Pip and easy_install; I think the `install_requires` keyword was added to distinguish dependencies by stage (there is also a `setup_requires`).

Comment: The Python docs are so good generally but they were making me irate on this detail.  The documentation for [`distutils.core.setup()`](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.setup) doesn't even *list* `install_requires` as a keyword.

Comment: @NickT: That's because `install_requires` is a `setuptools` extension.

Comment: Ah...is that due to the monkeypatching I hear of?

Comment: No, `setuptools` is an extension, not a monkeypatch.

Comment: The link for the Hitchhiker's Guide is now at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/

Comment: @KevinLondon: thanks, I'll seek out my other mentions too and update them.