# Why does Pip ignore conflicting dependencies?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-2.x

If I create a dummy package -- here's /tmp/example_package/setup.py (note the requirements):

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='my_project',
      description="Just a test project",
      version="1.0",
      py_modules=['sample'],
      install_requires=['requests > 0.12'])
```

Here's /tmp/example_package/sample.py:

```
import requests

def get_example():
    return requests.get("http://www.example.com")
```

Now, I create a virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv /tmp/foobar --distribute -p python2.7
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in /tmp/foobar/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /tmp/foobar/bin/python
Installing distribute.................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip................done.
$ source /tmp/foobar/bin/activate
```

I create a requirements.pip **with conflicting requirements**:

```
# this requires requests > 0.12:
file:///tmp/example_package

# but this conflicts:
requests==0.9.0
```

Pip happily installs this:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.pip                                                                                                                                                                       [18:40:10]
Unpacking ./example_package
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///tmp/example_package

Downloading/unpacking requests==0.9.0 (from -r requirements.pip (line 3))
  Downloading requests-0.9.0.tar.gz (55Kb): 55Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

Downloading/unpacking certifi>=0.0.4 (from requests==0.9.0->-r requirements.pip (line 3))
  Downloading certifi-0.0.8.tar.gz (118Kb): 118Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package certifi

Installing collected packages: requests, my-project, certifi
  Running setup.py install for requests

  Running setup.py install for my-project

  Running setup.py install for certifi

Successfully installed requests my-project certifi
Cleaning up...
```

Why does Pip allow this? My `example_package` won't work, because its requirements aren't met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of Pip. The requirements file trumps the requirements of the packages. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/775#issuecomment-12748095

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the pip source it seems like it should recursively add all the requirements to one big `RequirementSet`... and then crash out with a 'Duplicate requirement' exception...

Hmm.. are you sure your setup.py is correct?

Distutils has a `requires` keyword but not `install_requires`:
http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages

SO answers which reference this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686196/202168
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13468644/202168

Comment: I believe my setup.py is correct -- if I don't use `install_requires`, [pip ignores my dependencies in other circumstances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372336/how-do-i-make-pip-respect-requirements)

Comment: hmm, there's something fishy about `install_requires` here though https://bitbucket.org/carljm/python-distutils/src/48c42eeaee4410d76675b637bcd401b8919ff19a/core.py?at=default#cl-44 and http://svn.python.org/view/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py?view=log (line 170)

Comment: I think you're right, `install_requires` should be fine since Pip uses setuptools to do the installing http://stackoverflow.com/a/370062/202168  ...also, I'm hardly the first to notice, but holy moly Python packaging is a horrible mess when you look under the hood!

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/775 too. I'd assumed I was just doing something wrong, but it's possible this is a legitimate bug.